# Use Javascript to change a table cell color if its value is less than another

Tags: javascript, html-table, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here:

Just want cell `.tt` to be red when its numerical values is less than cell `dd`

HTML:

```
<table class="colorMe">
    <tr><td class="tt">2000</td><td>3500</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3000</td><td>2500</td></tr>
    <tr><td id="dd">4000</td><td>4500</td></tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(".colorMe .tt" ).each(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10);
    if (val < document.getElementById("dd");) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#F00000";
    }
});
```

No idea why this isn't working.

Comment: You're comparing the value of one element with the id of the other.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get both values as you did the first.

```js
$('.colorMe .tt').each(function() {
    var val = parseInt( $(this).text(), 10),
        dd = parseInt( $('#dd').text(), 10);
    if (val < dd) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

Comment: Javascript won't automatically convert the strings to number types; it will compare them lexicographically. `'2' < '10' == false`